# What is the safest way to perform critical operations in a single unit (without being affected by app terminate, enter background)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working a function that needs to reschedules all previous requested local notifications. Specifically, I want to perform a series of operations in a whole including remove pending notifications and recreate notification request and then add them to the notification center. At the same time, I worried that this process might be affected by application status (e.g. enter background, app terminate), broke data consistency. Is there a good way achieve these things on iOS platform?

**Edit:** I was being notified about the clarity of this question. I am looking for a way that allows me to write code in a [database transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)  fashion in swift. For example, is there a way to let a function finish its execution even when user choose to force terminate the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time) for instructions on how to let your app continue to run in the background when the user leaves the app, giving you up to 30 seconds to finish the task.

> Listing 1 shows an example that configures a background task so that the app may save data to its server, which could take longer than five seconds. The `beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:)` method returns an identifier that you must save and pass to the `endBackgroundTask(_:)` method.
>
> **Listing 1** Extending the app's background execution time
>
> ```
> func sendDataToServer( data : NSData ) {
>    // Perform the task on a background queue.
>    DispatchQueue.global().async {
>       // Request the task assertion and save the ID.
>       self.backgroundTaskID = UIApplication.shared.
>                  beginBackgroundTask (withName: "Finish Network Tasks") {
>          // End the task if time expires.
>          UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskID!)
>          self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
>       }
>            
>       // Send the data synchronously.
>       self.sendAppDataToServer( data: data)
>            
>       // End the task assertion.
>       UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskID!)
>       self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
>    }
> }
> ```

But there is nothing you can do if the user manually kills (aka “force quits”) app. In that scenario, your app will be summarily terminated.